# How can I extract all stages available for a particular api in AWS API gateway using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have an api, which is called/named **isw-hubs-api** in AWS API gateway. I am trying to extract all deployed stages of this api, i.e v1 and v2 using Terraform data resource as:

```
data "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "my_rest_api" {
  name = "isw-hubs-api"
}
```

However, i cannot understand how to extract the list of stages from the obtained data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws_api_gateway_stage` is a different resource type in Terraform, and there is no data source for that resource type. There is no way  to lookup a list of API Gateway stages in the Terraform AWS provider as far as I can tell.